# AES / Rijndael Test Vectors : what padding mode?

Tags: aes, rijndaelmanaged, encryption-symmetric

So I've been looking at these [test vectors](http://csrc.nist.gov/archive/aes/rijndael/rijndael-vals.zip) for the Known Answer Test for AES / Rijndael (with 128-bit block) in CBC mode, and I wonder:  **what kind of padding do they use?**  PKCS7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Zip archive you link to contains a file called `katmct.pdf` which describes how the tests are computed. There is no padding; for each test, the data already has the 128-bit length that the algorithm expects.

Comment: In retrospect, this was an RTFM question.  Thank you for being kind.